# How to display Steam Inventory on Website

Tags: json, api, html, steam

I just want to add a users inventory (specific, just one inventory) on a webpage.

I see this:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/
but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This one is what you're looking for:

> http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{SteamID64}/inventory/json/{appid}/2

You may also use the following, but due to the fact that not every user has set up a custom URL, I'd advice against it:

> http://steamcommunity.com/id/{customURL}/inventory/json/{appid}/2